Can I specify a different source address for masquerade (source NAT)?
Given 4 interfaces:

wg0: 192.0.2.186/29
wg1: 192.0.2.178/29
eth0.2: 192.0.2.209/28
eth0.3: 10.0.0.2/24

First three are public IP addresses, latter one is a private one.
Both wg0 and wg1 provide a redundant path to the internet.
Any computer in eth0.3 will have 10.0.0.2 as default gateway. In the normal configuration, a package to the internet will be routed via either wg0 or wg1 and NAT will be applied to replace the source IP with either 192.0.2.186 or 192.0.2.178 (depending on the interface)
Is it possible to instead replace the source address with 192.0.2.209?
Reason is that 192.0.2.209 is a public IP and is reachable via both wg0 and wg1, so a return packet would always find a way back as long as one link is up.
This would provide a redundant NAT link.
